# FullCalendar Not Rendering in Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have some basic custom tabs setup that function using click events that show/hide DIVs.

FullCalendar isn't showing up on one of those tabs despite using the `render` function ([docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render/)).

```
$(".tabs .tab").click (e) ->
  ...
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar "render"
```

The `#calendar` DIV is initially hidden, but from my understanding, the `render` function should force the calendar to render with each click. All of the other tabs work properly, so I know that it's not a problem with the show/hide functionality at all.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 div called "calendar"? Have you tried using the console to manually switch tab, make the div visible then call the render function? Does that work?

Comment: I only have one DIV with the ID `#calendar`. Chrome console doesn't report any errors in the JS. Calling the render function directly works, so it's not a problem with the library.

Comment: Ok, was just a couple of suggestions to help narrow it down if it was a library or other thing causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being related to the way I was showing/hiding DIVs-

The CSS selector that I was using to hide DIVs was too broad and ended up assigning `display: none;` to the calendar DIV (which was a child of the tab content DIVs).

The solution was to change:

```
$("#tab-contents div").hide()
```

To:

```
$("#tab-contents").children().hide
```

In the HTML the calendar was shown like this (in HAML):

```
#tab-contents
  #tab-calendar
    #calendar
  #tab-other
    ...
```

Thanks for the help and suggestions, and I should have posted more code in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

There usually are problems with some scripts no being able to work correctly on hidden DIV's.

I usually load page with everything visible, and after about 200ms I hide everything, that needs to be hidden.

For bootstrap tabs, I set every tab container "active" class and for tabs menu, I use this trigger script.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.my-tabs-control a').first().click();
}, 200);
```

You could try this solution for your own script.

Comment: That didn't work- the calendar appears for a second when the page is first rendered but disappears and doesn't show up in the tab afterwards.